# Подмена div другим div из файла

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как сделать, чтобы  `#content` менялся на определенный `div` из `conten.php`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#entry").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/conten.php",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").replaceWith(html);
            }
         });
         return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#entry').click(function()
{
    $('#content').load('conten.php #someid');
});
```

Comment: это понятно а как зделать замену #content на div из conten.php

Comment: динамически изменить id #content на другой? `$('#content').attr('id', 'newid');`

Comment: конкретизируйте заголовок и сам вопрос!

Comment: в этом моменте $("#content").replaceWith(здесь как то сделать выборку нужного div) или в url загрузить не полностью conten.php а только нужный div

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#entry").click(function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            url: "/conten.php", 
            cache: false, 
            success: function(html){ 
                //$("#content").replaceWith($('#someid', html).html());
                // поправка 2
                $(html).find('#someid').clone().insertAfter("#content");
                $("#content").remove();

            } 
        }); 
        return false; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: неработает (

Comment: А если так: 
$("#content").replaceWith($(html).find('#someid').html());

Comment: тоже исчезает #content но непоевляеться div из файла

Comment: @AhSerg тогда еще чуточку сложнее. Обновил пост.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#entry').click(function () {
        jQuery('#content').load("conten.php  #someid", function () {
            jQuery('#content').replaceWith(jQuery('#content').html());
        });
    });
});
```